# How to increase padding through every iteration?

Tags: angular

What I want is to add padding-left increasing for every iteration by 15px. Any suggestion how can I do that?  This is what I have so far.

```
getClassByValue(index){
    return {
        'padding-left': 15 * index + 'px'
    }
}
   <div class="ui-g-2" [ngClass]="getClassByValue(i)">{{orderItem.orditemnum}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="ui-g-2" *ngFor="item of items; let i = index" [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': 15 * i + 'px'}">{{item.orditemnum}}</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `[ngStyle]` instead of `[ngClass]`.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Something like this will do the job:

```
getStyleByValue(index){
    return {
        'padding-left': 15 * index + 'px'
    }
}

<div class="ui-g-2" [ngStyle]="getStyleByValue(i)">{{ orderItem.orditemnum }}</div>
```